# OSX: "Window Server: failed setting the front application to My App"

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, launch-agent, macos-windowserver

I am launching a `launchAgent` from a post install script using the following command:

```
su -l $LOGGED_IN_USER -c "/bin/launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.myApp.mac.agent.plist"
```

The agent displays a status item (`NSStatusItem`) with a couple of menu options. One of them has a settings option. Clicking this will open an `NSWindow`, with few `NSTextField`s. At times, though this window is the top most, whatever I type goes to the underlying app. I am unable to type anything into the text field. Whenever this happens, I notice the following log in the console:

```
WindowServer[97]: [cps/setfront] Failed setting the front application to MyApp, psn 0x0-0xb20b2, securitySessionID=0x186c5, err=-600
```

This is not a consistent behaviour. Any idea why this log comes? And is there any work around for this? Is it ok to launch the agent using `su -l`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know *exactly* why you're getting that error and behavior. I recommend reading [Technical Note TN2083: Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html). It explains in detail the various facets of the execution context of a process and how that affects what a process can do. That includes whether or not a process can connect to the Window Server.

For what it's worth, error -600 is `procNotFound`, whose description is "no eligible process with specified descriptor". It seems that the Window Server is not able to find a process with the given process serial number (PSN) in the given security session.

I would not use `-l` in your `sudo` command. A user's login scripts can do all sorts of crazy things and you don't those done by your installer. However, I don't believe that's related to the main problem.